Persistent systemd-logind error in Fedora Silverblue: Failed to open '/boot//loader/entries'
I'm running Fedora Silverblue (version 40.20241018.0) and I'm encountering a persistent error with systemd-logind. After every boot, I see the following error message repeated several times in the system logs:
Key points:

This error occurs consistently across multiple boots and persists after system upgrades.
The error message contains a path with a double slash (/boot//loader/entries).
Despite this error, the system appears to function normally.
I've verified that /boot/loader/entries exists and contains the expected bootloader configuration files.

I've tried the following troubleshooting steps:

Updating the system using rpm-ostree upgrade
Redeploying the current commit using ostree admin deploy
Checking for unusual symlinks or directory structures in /boot

None of these steps have resolved the issue.
My questions are:

What might be causing systemd-logind to attempt to access a path with a double slash?
Could this error be indicative of a larger issue, despite the system functioning normally?
Are there any other troubleshooting steps I should try to resolve this?
Is this a known issue with systemd-logind on OSTree-based systems?


I think you forgot to include the actual error message :)

I reported the issue upstream, you can find more details there:
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/35293

Please report on your bug RE: symlinks in the directory.  I just read your bug and someone is modifying the tags....
